# Lebesgue inner measure formula

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I cannot prove this formula:
$E$ is measurable and $A$ is any subset of $E$
show that $m(E)=m_*(A) +m^*(E-A)$.

Define inner measure of $A$ by $m_∗(A)=\sup(m(F))$, where the supremum is taken over all closed subsets $F$ of $E$.

$m(E)$ means $E$ is measurable and for outer measure of $E$, cover $E$ by countable collection $S$ of intervals $I_k$. i.e. $m^\ast(E)=\inf \sum \nu(I_k)$

Thanks and regards.

Comment: What did you try? Can you recall the definition of inner and outer measure, then try to see how it may solve the problem.

Comment: In any case, when you ask it here you should provide the definitions you are using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the little information you give on what you know, this is bound to be somewhat tricky.

Here's an outline for a proof of the following more general formula:
For every measurable set $E$ and an arbitrary set $A$ we have
$$m(E) = m_\ast(E \cap A) + m^\ast(E \smallsetminus A).\tag{$*$}$$

1. Prove that for all $A$ the identity $m^\ast(A) = \inf{\{m(G)\,:\,G \supset A \text{ measurable}\}}$ holds.

   [If $m^\ast(A) = \infty$ then ... If $m^\ast(A) \lt \infty$ take $G_n \supset A$ to be a union of intervals with $m(G_n) \lt m^\ast(A) + \frac{1}{n}$ and put $G = \bigcap G_n$.]
2. Prove that for all $A$ we have $m_\ast(A) = \sup{\{m(F)\,:\,F \subset A \text{ is measurable}\}}.$
3. If the measure of $E$ is *finite*, we have $m^\ast(E \smallsetminus A) \lt \infty$ and we may write 
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   m(E) - m^\ast(E \smallsetminus A)
   & = 
   m(E) -  \inf{\{m(G)\,:\,G \supset E \smallsetminus A \text{ is measurable}\}} \\
   & =
   m(E) -  \inf{\{m(G)\,:\,E \supset G \supset E \smallsetminus A \text{ is measurable}\}} \\
   & = m(E) - \inf{\{m(E) - m(F)\,:\,F \subset E \cap A \text{ is measurable}\}} 
   \tag{#} \\
   & = \sup{\{m(F)\,:\,F \subset E \cap A \text{ is measurable}\}} \\
   & = m_\ast(E \cap A)
   \end{align*}
   $$
   so that $m(E) = m_\ast(E\cap A) + m^\ast(E \smallsetminus A)$, which is the desired formula (for sets $E$ of *finite* measure).

   [Note that in $(\#)$ we used measurability of $E$ and finiteness of its measure to conclude that for $E \supset G \supset E \cap A$ and $F = E \smallsetminus G$ we have $m(E) = m(G) + m(F)$.]
4. By definition
   $m_\ast (A) = \sup{\{m(F)\,:\,F \subset A \text{ is closed}\}}$.
   For each closed $F \subset E \cap A$ we have 
   $$
   m(E) = m(F) + m(E \smallsetminus F) \geq m(F) + m^\ast(E \smallsetminus A)
   $$ 
   since measurability of $F$ gives
   $m(E \smallsetminus F) = m^\ast(E \smallsetminus F)$,
   and since $E \smallsetminus F \supset E \smallsetminus A$ yields 
   $m^\ast(E \smallsetminus F) \geq m^\ast(E \smallsetminus A)$ because $m^\ast$ is monotone.

   Taking the supremum over all closed $F \subset E \cap A$ we get 
   $$
   m(E) \geq m_\ast(E \cap A) + m^\ast(E \smallsetminus A).\tag{1}
   $$
5. Finally, we can establish $(\ast)$ for arbitrary measurable $E$ by observing that monotonicity of $m_\ast$ and $m^\ast$ give
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   m_\ast(E \cap A) + m^\ast(E \smallsetminus A) 
   &\geq \sup{\{m_\ast (F \cap A) + m^\ast(F \smallsetminus A)\,:\,F \subset E \text{ measurable, }m(F) \lt \infty\}} \\
   &= \sup{\{m(F)\,:\,F \subset E \text{ measurable, } m(F) \lt \infty\}} \\
   &= m(E)
    \end{align*}
   $$
   and combining this with the inequality in $(1)$. In the first equality here we used what we proved in 3.