# Outer measure of a union of 2 subsets of disjoint measurable sets of real numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Every set mentioned is a subset of the real numbers.

Let $m^*(C)$ denote the outer measure of a set $C$. Let $E$ be $any$ set and $A,B$ be measurable, disjoint sets. I'm trying to show that $$m^*(E\cap (A\cup B))=m^*(E\cap A)+m^*(E\cap B).$$

Proof: 
($\le$) follows by the countable subadditivity of the outer measure since
$$E\cap (A\cup B)= (E\cap A)\cup (E\cap B).$$

Here's where I get stuck:

($\ge$) My attempts have reduced to something of the form:

1. There are bounded open sets $G_1, G_2$ containing $E\cap A, E\cap
       B$, respectively, such that $$m(G_1)\ge m^*(E\cap A),\quad m(G_2)\ge
       m^*(E\cap B).$$ Hence $$m^*(E\cap A)+m^*(E\cap B)\le m(G_1)+m(G_2).$$
   And I would like to extend this inequality to $m(G_1\cup G_2)$ but I
   know that's not even true, especially since the sets $G_1, G_2$ may
   not even be disjoint.
2. I also tried de la Vallée-Poussin Criterion: Let $\epsilon>0$. Since
   $A, B$ are measurable, there are closed subsets $F_1, F_2$ of $A,B$
   respectively, such that $m^*(A\cap E - F_1)+ m^*(B\cap
       E-F_2)<\epsilon$. Even if I could show, $$|m^*(E\cap (A\cup
       B)-[(F_1\cup F_2))+ m^*(A\cap E - F_1)+ m^*(B\cap
       E-F_2)]|<\epsilon.$$

   I'm not sure what that would mean.

**What I know:**

- Measure has only been defined for bounded sets.
- A bounded set $A$ is $measurable$ if its outer and inner measures
      are equal; if so, the measure of $A$ is the common value of these
      measures.
- Differences, countable unions, countable intersections of measurable
  sets are measurable.
- The union of a set of pairwise disjoint measurable sets is
  measurable, with the measure of the union equal to the sum of the
  measures of the sets in the union.
- Outer and inner measures are monotone increasing functions.
- Countable subadditivity for outer measure, which states that if $A$
  is a countable or finite union of sets $A_i$ then $m^*(A)\le \sum
     m^*(A_i)$.
- De la Vallée-Poussin Criterion, which states that a bounded set $A$
  is measurable iff for every $\epsilon >0$ there is a closed set
  $B\subset A$ such that $m^*(A-B)< \epsilon$.
- For any bounded set $B$, I can always find a set $C$ that is a
  countable intersection of open sets for which $B \subset C$ and
  $m^*(B)=m^*(C)$.
- If $A$ and $B$ are measurable sets, then $m(A\cup B) + m(A\cap B) =
     m(A) + m(B)$.
- If $A$ is bounded and $I$ is an open interval containing $E$, then
  $m^*(E) + m_*(I-E) = m(I)$.

Comment: Why are subsets of measurable sets bounded? Consider for example $]0,\infty[\subset \mathbb{R}$, where $\mathbb{R}$ is measurable and $]0,\infty[$ is unbounded.

Comment: So far my notes have only defined measurability for bounded sets. Haven't gotten there yet, but thanks for the insight.

Comment: Perhaps [useful](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/81875/8271)

Comment: Notice that Caratheodory Criterion is equivalent to the problem you pose. You can get a proof of the Caratheodory Criterion for example from the Wheeden & Zygmund's _Measure and Integral_ book, to get some inspiration.

Comment: @leo Thanks for the link you sent, but the equation in that question has both inner and outer measure. Even though my set $A$ is measurable, we cannot conclude that $A\cap E$ is. I proved the Caratheodory Criterion by using the result I am trying to prove. My goal is to create/find a solution to the reverse inequality that I posed, rather than using the proof of Caratheodory (which is a later problem in my notes).

Comment: My last resort is to note that, as you said, these two problems are equivalent and then to give a proof of Caratheodory. Since Caratheodory comes later in my notes, I am assuming this problem can be done without Caratheodory's result.

Comment: That's the proof I have in mind. They are equivalent so you can prove your assertion by proving Cratheodory "from scratch". I suggested that way in order to get some inspiration to proceed the way you want. Let me write something. Perhaps I come back with an answer in while.

Comment: I like Byron's edit.

Comment: Byron, nicely presented. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We start with a little Lemma:

**Lemma.** *Let $E\subseteq \Bbb R$. If $H\supseteq E$ is a $G_\delta$ set (countable intersection of open sets) such that*
$$m(H)=m^\ast(E),$$
*then for every $C\subseteq\Bbb R$*
$$m^\ast(H\cap C)=m^\ast(E\cap C).$$

*Proof.* Let $C\subseteq\Bbb R$. In the following the superscript $^c$ means complement.
$$\begin{align*}
m^\ast(H\cap C) &\leq m^\ast(H\cap C\cap E\cap C)+m^\ast((H\cap C)\setminus (E\cap C))\\
                &= m^\ast(E\cap C) + m^\ast((H\cap C)\cap (E\cap C)^c)\\
                &= m^\ast(E\cap C) + m^\ast(C\cap (H\setminus E))\\
                &\leq m^\ast(E\cap C) + m^\ast(H\setminus E)\\
                &= m^\ast(E\cap C)
\end{align*}$$
The inequality $m^\ast(H\cap C)\geq m^\ast(E\cap C)$ comes free by the monotony of the outer measure since $H\supseteq E$.

**Proof of $m^\ast(E\cap (A\cup B))\geq m^\ast(E\cap A)+m^\ast(E\cap B)$.**

Pick $H\supseteq E$ a $G_\delta$ set so that $m(H)=m^\ast(E)$. Then
$$\begin{align*}
m^\ast(E\cap (A\cup B)) &= m^\ast(H\cap (A\cup B)) &&\text{by the Lemma}\\
                        &= m(H\cap A) + m(H\cap B) &&\text{($^\ast$)}\\
                        &\geq m^\ast(E\cap A) + m^\ast(E\cap B) &&\text{by the monotony of the outer measure.}
\end{align*}$$
($^\ast$) because here we are dealing with measurable sets (of finite measure).

**Observation.** Notice that such a $G_\delta$ set $H$ always exist even if $E$ is unbounded.

Comment: I can see that such a set $H$ with the same outer measure of $E$ will exists. But how do you know that the countable intersection $H$ will be always be measurable?

Comment: If you can prove that open sets are measurable then that's a corolary. Do you can?

Comment: Yes, but the intersection of open sets isn't always open. Take $A_n = (-1/n,1/n)$ in the real line. Then $\cap A_n$ is a singleton, which won't be open in the real line.

Comment: You're right, it's a singleton, a singleton have outer measure zero so it is measurable. In the other hand, if you can proof that an open set is measurable by the third bullet of **What you know** it follows that a countable intersection of measurable sets is always measurable.

Comment: Thank you, and thanks to everyone who contributed.

Comment: @Broseph are you fully satisfied? It's all clear?

Comment: Yes, everything follows.

Comment: there is a mistake in the proof of your Lemma. You are assuming that $E$ is measurable. that is, you said that $m^{*}(H\setminus E) = 0$, which is only true if $E$ is measurable.

Comment: @UlisesNunez If $E$ is measurable, then certainly $m^\ast(H) = m^\ast(E)$ implies $m^\ast(H\setminus E)=0$. But the implication is not true in general. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/56309/8271).

Comment: The Lemma you wrote doesn’t start with the assumption that $E$ is measurable. Thus, I wonder what assumptions you used in order to conclude that $m^{*}(H\setminus E)=0$. Maybe I’m missing something.

Comment: No. You're right. The proof as it stands is not correct.

Comment: @UlisesNunez The proof can be fixed by adding the equality $m(H) = m^\ast(E)$ to the inequality $m^\ast(H\cap C)\leq m^\ast(E\cap C) + m^\ast(H\setminus E)$ and using the fact that $H$ is measurable (Carathéodory). But the intention of the OP was to prove Carathéodory's criterion using the equality he wants to prove. So this calls for a lower technology proof. I'll probably delete this post.

Comment: Is there a way to generalize this to a countably infinite union?

$m^*\left(S \cap \{\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n\}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}m^*\left(S\cap E_n\right)$

where $E_n$ are a sequence of disjoint Lebesgue measurable sets, and $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 4):

Put $F=E\cap (A\cup B)$ then, since $A$ is $m^*$-measurable, we have that 
$$
m^*(F)= m^*(F\cap A) + m^*(F\cap A^c) = m^*(E\cap A)+m^*(E\cap B)
$$
since $A\cap B =\emptyset$

Comment: I want to use the equation in my problem to prove the Caratheodory Crtieria / the equation you just used, so I don't want to assume this equation is true yet.

Comment: @Broseph: I suggest making explicit in the question your definition  of measurability, as well as the results that are available so that a more appropiate answer may be given.

Answer (score -2):

It can be shown that there exists nonvoid disjoint subsets A,B of R such that m*(A U B) is strictly less than m*(A) + m*(B) using the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: You still need to elaborate